# Determining the error of estimated data from other known data

Tags: estimation, accuracy

**Situation**

I have a number of defined areas throughout a city that I am trying to develop population estimates for.

Census data is the basis for the estimate.

My custom areas do not neatly align with census boundaries.

I intend to use a method where I firstly determine the proportion of my area within each census boundary and use this proportion to estimate the population. For example if my polygon covers 20% of a given census boundary, I am saying the population of my polygon within that census boundary is 0.2xCensus_Population.

**Determining accuracy**

To determine the accuracy of this method I have applied it using known values from different scaled census boundaries. They are CB1 (the smallest) and CB2 (larger).

A number of CB1s make up a CB2.

I selected hundreds of CB1s within my study area that are contained within a total of 100 CB2s (I purposefully excluded some CB1s so that they don't make up a complete CB2 in any of the 100 CB2s).

I summed the area of the CB1s within each CB2. I then used this area to determine the proportion of CB1 area within each CB2, and multiplied this proportion by the population recorded for the CB2.

I then compared this estimate to the known values of the sum of the population of the CB1s within each CB2. This gives me a difference between actual census results, and my proportion area method.

Across all 100 CB2s, I calculated the standard deviation of the difference between estimate and actual to be 50.

The average difference between estimate and actual across all 100 census areas was 9.

The average estimated population (per area within a given CB2) was 158.

I used Z values of 2.58, 1.96, and 1.645 to calculate error margins on the difference using Z*(SD/SQRT of 100). Results were 99% +/- 13, 95% +/-10, and 90 +/-8.

The estimation results in positive and negative values - i.e. sometimes the result is a higher population than actual, and sometimes it is less.

**My questions**

Is this a valid way to develop an error margin for the proposed method?

How do I apply it? Let’s say I apply my method to my custom polygon and it results in an estimated population of 20. Based on the error calculation I described, can I then say the population is 20 +/- 13 (to be 99% confident)? Or can I apply the error as a percentage (i.e. I determine the percentage of error based on 13/average population (8%) – which would be 20 +/- 8%?). Or am I on the wrong track completely?

Do I need to factor in the average difference between estimate and actual? I did the same process for another way of estimating population. Compared to the method I describe here it had smaller errors, smaller SD, but a significantly larger average difference. Which is the more accurate method?

Are you aware of any standard methods that already exist to do what I am trying to do? This would be really helpful.

I've tried searching but I don't know enough about statistics to search with meaningful terms, or to comprehend a lot of the terminology I come across. As you can probably tell from my questions, I really have no idea what I'm doing.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is essentially right.  Good for you! You should have been very confident of your answer!